# Grammarly CKEditor 4 incompatibility

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am currently using CKEditor 4 and facing issues with the Grammarly chrome extension. Despite using Grammarly in CKEditor 4, the actual content doesn't get updated, although it appears as if the changes are applied within the editor. Additionally, I have a few questions regarding this:

Is there a Grammarly plugin available for CKEditor 4? I have attempted to use grammeryly in ckeditor4, but the content doesn't get updated.

I have also tried to enable the NativeSpellChecker feature in CKEditor 4, but it doesn't seem to work. The spell checker doesn't highlight any errors.

Furthermore, I would like to know about the support and deprecation status of CKEditor 4. Are there any plans to discontinue support for CKEditor 4, and if so, when is it expected to be deprecated?

If anyone has encountered similar issues with the Grammarly plugin or NativeSpellChecker in CKEditor 4 or has any insights or solutions to these problems, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thank you in advance!

I was expecting the Grammarly plugin to highlight errors and provide suggestions for improvements.
No errors are highlighted, and the spell checker does not provide any suggestions.